# Read image grayscale opencv 3.0.0-dev

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale

I am trying to read images directly as black and white.

I recently updated my OpenCv version to 3.0.0-dev, and the code that I used before does not work anymore.

```
   img = cv2.imread(f, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

works fine for 2.4 but does not work for the new version, as there is no field `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`.

Any suggestions?

Note: I know that `cv2.imread(f,0)` will work, but I do not like having unnamed constants in my code.
Thanks!

Comment: did you try `cv2.LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`? I guess all the `CV_` were renamed

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The flag has been renamed to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. Generally speaking, flags now have names prefixed in a manner that relates to the function to which they refer. (e.g. `imread` flags start with `IMREAD_`, `cvtColor` flags start with `COLOR_`, etc.)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation, will probably help in the future as well.

Comment: The documentation should be updated accordingly: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html?highlight=imread#Mat imread(const String& filename, int flags)

Comment: @EduardFeicho 's Link is down, here is a current one https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80

Answer (score 35):

Try this it works for me

```
import cv2
im_gray = cv2.imread('gray_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('blackwhite.png', im_bw)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works for me everytime

```
import cv2
gray_img = cv2.imread('img.png', 0)
cv2.imshow(gray_img)
```

Comment: My guess is downvote(s) because OP wrote "I know that cv2.imread(f,0) will work, but I do not like having unnamed constants in my code."

Comment: And opencv docs use such line a lot https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html