# Which parameter I can replace "cv2.cv.CV_INTER_AREA" in OpenCV 3.0?

Tags: interpolation, opencv3.0

OpenCV 3.0 has deprecated `cv2.cv`. I was looking for another function to use in resize.

```
im = cv2.resize(im, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.cv.CV_INTER_AREA)
```

What parameter I can replace `cv2.cv.CV_INTER_AREA` with?

Answer (score 2):

I did a little research, I can replace by:

```
cv2.INTER_AREA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print OpenCV documentation to a readable HTML file using the following command and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search through in your web browser.

```
pydoc cv2
```

or you can use the following in CLI:

```
import cv2
help(cv2)
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23345253/3303059