# How to change an image to grayscale represented as a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

**Preface:**

I have an image of a coin. This is any generic image of a coin that I plug into python, and I want to make this coin a grayscale image. The variable `P` represents the array containing the RGB values for the picture of the coin, and I believe that I can turn RGB to grayscale by changing any RGB values under `128` to `0` while turning any RGB values above `128` to `255`.

**Error:**

I am trying to use a for loop to turn the values in the array generated by `P` to `0`, `128`, and `255`. When I do so this way, I encounter the error as:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int' ".

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
P = plt.imread('coin.jpg')
for item in enumerate(P):
    if item < 128:
        item = 0
    elif item > 128:
        item = 255
```

Comment: Please note that enumerate returns a tuple : index and value. So `item` here is a tuple. You might have to compare it with `item[1]`

Comment: Apart from the `enumerate` problem, that code won't loop correctly over your pixels. But even if you fix that, your algorithm won't convert an RGB image to greyscale, or black & white.

Comment: I don't know matplotlib, but it would be easy to use PIL to load & convert the image to greyscale or B & W. And Numpy can easily load PIL images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read image grayscale opencv 3.0.0-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339315/read-image-grayscale-opencv-3-0-0-dev)

Comment: You are talking about converting normal images to greyscale images, but what you really do is converting them into [binary images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image). What do you really want?

Answer (score 4):

Two issues. Firstly, you are not converting to greyscale. Secondly, the whole point of `numpy` is to vectorise and avoid `for` loops because they are slow.

So starting with this image:

[image]

You want something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load coins and convert to greyscale
grey = np.array(Image.open('coins.png').convert('L'))

# Threshold at 128
thresholded=((grey>128)*255).astype(np.uint8)

# Save
Image.fromarray(thresholded).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sruthi V is right. enumerate() returns a tuple.

So instead of 
`if item < 128`
it should be 
`if item[1] < 128`

Or you could just remove enumerate() entirely if you aren't using it.
It seems it will work fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Hereby I quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale):

> ## Converting color to grayscale
>
> Conversion of an arbitrary color image to grayscale is not unique in general; different weighting of the color channels effectively represent the effect of shooting black-and-white film with different-colored photographic filters on the cameras.

So, you need to implement an algorithm to convert original images into greyscale images, that is, to convert the *tuples* of color in RGB space you get from `enumerate()` to a *tuple* of color in greyscale space.

Then if you want to convert greyscale images into binary images, you need [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)).

> ## Thresholding (image processing)
>
> Thresholding is the simplest method of image segmentation. From a grayscale image, thresholding can be used to create binary images.

Read more about *Greyscaling*:

- [Seven grayscale conversion algorithms (with pseudocode and VB6 source code)](http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/)