# Python save and read a grayscale image in two dimension array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, computer-vision

I want to save an image without any channel, so the dimension would only be 2. Thus, is there a way I do it in matplotlib?

I have already tried using

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imsave('img.png', image, cmap='gray')
```

but when I read it using

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imread('img.png')
```

The dimension is 3. So I'm confusing how. I know maybe I can't use imread but what can I do instead?

Comment: A grayscale image has 3 dimention, the third one represent light level

Comment: Thank you! Already changed the question. So do you know how to make them 2 dimension? like array.shape = (256,256), not (256,256,3) ?

Comment: You meant (256,256, 1) right ? because (256,256) is not an image

Comment: try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339315/read-image-grayscale-opencv-3-0-0-dev

Comment: Nop, but I can also export the array to npy with (256,256) and import them with the same 2 dimension. So can I achieve this using matplotlib?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the system is linux and I can't install opencv on it and I tried.

Comment: An grayscale image consist of x axis, y axis and a color depth, if you're only saving 2 dimentions then it wouldn't be an image  Also I'm using ubuntu and have opencv installed

Comment: @YukiShioriii: That makes no sense. A gray-scale image is a 2D matrix.

Comment: From the docs, it looks like matplotlib only saves RGB or RGBA format image files. You’ll have to use a different package to save a gray-scale image. OpenCV as suggested below is just one option. There are many. Try PIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have opencv installed, you can try:

```
cv2.imread('1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Also, you can also try PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(array)
```

***I didn't see this one on the internet, but this one works! thanks to my teacher!***

```
skimage.io.imsave('1.png', np.around(image*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

To use this, you have to have skimage preinstalled.

```
pip3 install scikit-image
```

Thanks @[Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) in the comment above to point out that

> "From the docs, it looks like matplotlib only saves RGB or RGBA format
> image files. You’ll have to use a different package to save a
> gray-scale image. OpenCV as suggested below is just one option. There
> are many. Try PIL."

Give him an upvote when you saw it!